# How to access element from json object inside a dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

I'm getting a string from the server as an API call response which is an encoded token. I decode the token and getting this payload. I can access the "data" or "iat" value as key-value pair but how to loop throw and access the element inside the "data" key? Please help.

```
["iat": 1594655088, "data": 
[{"questionCode":"7a75bf82baea11eabffcfa5fb99b9064","question":"In which country you need to 
visit to explore Petra? ","image":"https://tbbd-flight.s3.ap-southeast- 
1.amazonaws.com/quiz/UihDZXwomcu-d2viNsL7UiewQYiqqpXJ.png","options": 
[{"answerCode":"7a766accbaea11ea8317fa5fb99b9064","answer":"Malaysia "}, 
{"answerCode":"7a766b94baea11eaaf95fa5fb99b9064","answer":"Jordan "}, 
{"answerCode":"7a766c02baea11ea8b10fa5fb99b9064","answer":"Vietnam "}, 
{"answerCode":"7a766c66baea11eaa920fa5fb99b9064","answer":"Australia "}]},

{"questionCode":"8b02bff8baea11ea9882fa5fb99b9064","question":"Worlds one of the most 
luxarious hotel \"Burj Al Arab\"  in which country?","image":"https://tbbd-flight.s3.ap- 
southeast-1.amazonaws.com/quiz/QTKKvpJxhWY7DA-G4bhnOdPoQ02WsR4o.png","options": 
[{"answerCode":"8b036cd2baea11eaaa03fa5fb99b9064","answer":"France"}, 
{"answerCode":"8b036d9abaea11ea8085fa5fb99b9064","answer":"Dubai"}, 
{"answerCode":"8b036e12baea11eabafefa5fb99b9064","answer":"England"}, 
{"answerCode":"8b036e80baea11eabf20fa5fb99b9064","answer":"Canada"}]}
]]
```

Comment: You can use SwiftyJSON 
ref: [link](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: Add the code you have so far and explain the issue with it

Comment: @AzimShaikh no point in using an old 3rd party library when the built in json support is so good, check out Codable

Answer (score 0):

Use **`Codable`** to decode the above JSON `data` using below models,

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let iat: Int
    let data: [Question]
}

struct Question: Codable {
    let questionCode, question: String
    let image: String
    let options: [Option]
}
```

Parse the JSON `data` like so,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    let questions = response.data
    questions.forEach {
        print($0.questionCode)
        //use more fields here...
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Do we really need another answer for this kind of question that we see all the time?

Comment: @PGDev The problem is when I place "data" inside "let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)" its giving me an error, that is: "Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type 'Data'". I know how to map but can't get this error here. Sorry for didn't mention it on the question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't think even after having so many answers for the same thing is still helping OP.

Comment: I meant for this kind of low quality json question where we see no effort from OP just some json message that OP expects us to write the correct code for